# C++ nonlohmann json read child object

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

i'm actually working on a little program and i need to read a json file.
i'm using C++ and the nlohmann json libraries.

My current code

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv){
    ifstream ifs("Myjson.json");
    json j = json::parse(ifs);
    cout << "Front image path : "<< j["front"]["imagePath"]  << "\n";
    cout << "Back image path : " << j["back"]["imagePath"] << "\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

MyJson.json

```
{
    "Side": [
        {
            "camera": "22344506",
            "width": 19860,
            "nbParts": 662,
            "wParts": 30,
            "height": 1600,
            "imagePath": "./Tchek_buffer/22344506.png"
        },
        {
            "camera": "22344509",
            "width": 5296,
            "nbParts": 662,
            "wParts": 8,
            "height": 1600,
            "imagePath": "./Tchek_buffer/22344509.png"
        },
    ],
    "front": {
        "camera": "22344513",
        "image": null,
        "width": 1200,
        "height": 1600,
        "imagePath": "./Tchek_buffer/22344513.png"
    },
    "back": {
        "camera": "22344507",
        "image": null,
        "width": 1600,
        "height": 1200,
        "imagePath": "./Tchek_buffer/22344507.png"
    },
}
```

I can easily read and display the "back" and the "front" object but i can't read the scanner object. 
i want to get the "imagePath" of all "scanner" object

i tried thing like

```
cout << "scanner image path : " << j["scanner"]["imagePath"] << "\n";
cout << "scanner image path : " << j["scanner[1]"]["imagePath"] << "\n";
cout << "scanner image path : " << j["scanner"[1]]["imagePath"] << "\n";
```

i only get "null" result

if someone can help me and explain me how i can make it work .

Comment: "Side" = "scanner" ?

Comment: If you do mean "Side" it would be `cout << "scanner image path : " << j["Side"][0]["imagePath"] << "\n";` (array indices start at zero)

Comment: j["Side"][0]["imagePath"] and j["Side"][1]["imagePath"]

Comment: As a side note - you can use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to see that your json contains 2 invalid commas

Comment: Yes  side = scanner , my bad . Thx for you answere !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `scanner` is in fact `Side` in the json.

Your trials did the following:

- Access the "imagePath" property of the list
- Access the "scanner[1]" property of the list
- Access the "c" (second character) property of the list.

So the dirty way to go would be :

```
cout << "scanner image path : " << j["Side"][0]["imagePath"] << "\n";
cout << "scanner image path : " << j["Side"][1]["imagePath"] << "\n";
```

And the proper one would be:

```
for (auto& element : j["Side"])
  cout << "scanner image path : " << element["imagePath"] << "\n";
```

Comment: The "proper way" depends on many things. If the size of the array is always 2 (for left-side and right-side), the proper way is not a range-based loop. ;-)

Comment: How does "for (auto& element : j["Side"])
  cout << "scanner image path : " << element["imagePath"] << "\n";"       
 work ?

Comment: As long as the invariant was not properly stated, I always assume a list to be of any size.

Comment: @EyRaG_ have a look at "range based" for loops. It is the C++ equivalent of what other languages call the `foreach`. It is basically syntactic sugar to avoid the iterator pain.

Comment: Note that it's only available from C++11.

Comment: Which is a given since C++11 is a requirement to use `nlohmann/json`

Comment: I will have more than 2 side object so doing a loop will help . Thanks for your answers. i just don't understand the "&" after the "auto" and what "element" is  but i still know how that work . for each j side element display imagepath

Comment: The `auto` is there to let C++ infer the type itself. The & is there to tell it to retrieve the element by non const reference. You could use just `auto` for a copy or `auto const&` for a const reference. Get some doc about C++ references and the `auto` keyword. `auto` is a major feature of C++11. Here, `element` has type `json&`.

Comment: I'll check some doc right now . Thank you for your reply .  I did not think I had an answer so quickly

Comment: @Jean-BernardJansen that's maybe a newbie question but , can't i change the loop syntaxe with something like for (i=0 , i < auto& element :J[scanner], i++)  then put                                                                                             
 cout << "scanner image path : " << j["Side"][i]["imagePath"] << "\n";

Comment: Yes you can. You can write `for (size_t i = 0; i < j["Side"].size(); ++i) { /* code */ }`

Comment: Yea thx that's exqctly what i wanted, have a last question about vectorname.push_back, can i merge a string and a variable and put in in the same index ? Like this : vectorname.push_back("element" + i)

Comment: Well thats pretty out of scope. It wont work this way, you have to learn how to manipulate strings in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `"Side"` and `"scanner"` is equivalent in your question. You probably did a mismatch between the tags.

I don't know this library, but I suppose it's something like that:

```
cout << "scanner image path 1 : " << j["scanner"][0]["imagePath"] << "\n";
cout << "scanner image path 2 : " << j["scanner"][1]["imagePath"] << "\n";
```

You can find an example from documentation [here](http://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a57703688bee6b9736ab3a430d8d246f2.html).